# Laravel 5.4 Mail, passing data

Tags: laravel, email

I'm trying to send an email to myself with a simple contact form in Laravel 5.4.

My form is 4 inputs: Nom, prenom, email and message.
I just want to send an email with data in my mail template

This is my controller:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'nom' => 'required|alpha',
    'prenom' => 'required|alpha',
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'message' => 'required',
    ]);

    $data = [
      'nom' => $request->nom,
      'prenom' => $request->prenom,
      'email' => $request->email,
      'message' => $request->message,
    ];

    Mail::to('myadress')->send(new Contact($data));
```

This is my "Contact" Mail:

```
public $data;

public function __construct($data)
{
    $this->nom = $data['nom'];
    $this->prenom = $data['prenom'];
    $this->email = $data['email'];
    $this->message = $data['message'];
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.hello')->with([
                'nom' => $this->nom,
                'prenom' => $this->prenom,
                'email' => $this->email,
                'message' => $this->message,
            ]);
}
```

And this is my mail template:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<h2>Demande d'informations </h2>

<div>
    <p>
      Vous recevez ce mail via le formulaire de contact du site .
    </p>
    <p>
      Adresse mail du contact: {{ $email }}
    </p>
    <p>
      Nom: {{ $nom }} / Prénom: {{ $prenom }}
    </p>
    <h3>Message du contact:</h3>
    <p>
      {{ $message }}
    </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I get an error message saying I can't pass an object as string.
Thank for your help, it's the first time I use Laravel Mail

Comment: Been a minute since I've used the Mail facade. But I think here's your problem: `Mail::to('myadress')->send(new Contact($data));` I think send(..) expects string and you're passing it a model.

Comment: In the documentation, we have this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#sending-mail

Comment: Oh ok. Nevermind me then I didn't know there was `php artisan make:mail` for generating markdown classes. I thought you're passing in a Model (as in DB model).

Comment: Nope indeed, I just want to pass some data in the mail :)

Comment: How can i achieve this in laravel 5.8, anyone?

Comment: @udemethegrtman pls see my new answer bellow.

Answer (score 12):

So, I found my problem:

```
public function __construct($data) {
    $this->data = $data;
}
```

And then:

```
public function build() {
    return $this->from('mailadress@blabla', 'my site')
    ->subject('hello you')
    ->view('emails.hello')->with(['data', $this->data]);
}
```

In my blade file:

```
Adresse mail du contact: {{ $data['email'] }}
```

**Just because I tried to display an array as object in my view...**

So my bad !

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for passing data to your email template in **Laravel 5.8** (also working with 5.5/5.6/5.7 I think)

Here is my Controller:

```php
    <?php  
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Mail\ClientMail;    
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;    
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;    
    use App\Http\Requests\SendClientMail; 

    class  ClientContactController  extends  Controller

    {

        public  function  index()

        {

            return  view('client_contact');

        }



        public  function  send(SendClientMail  $request)

        {

            Mail::to("myemailaddress@agency.com")->send(new  ClientMail($request));         
            return  redirect()->route('client-contact')->with('flash-message', 'Your email has been sent! Thank you!');

        }

    }
```

Next is my ClientMail.php file (app/Mail/ClientMail.php)

```php
    <?php

    namespace App\Mail;

    use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;    
    use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;    
    use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;    
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;    


    class  ClientMail  extends  Mailable

    {

        use  Queueable, SerializesModels;

        // array with all your data
        protected  $infos;



        /**

        * Create a new message instance.

        *

        * @return  void

        */

        public  function  __construct($infos)

        {

            $this->infos  =  $infos;

        }



        /**

        * Build the message.

        *

        * @return $this

        */

        public  function  build()

        {

            return  $this->from('sendingemail@mywebsite.com')

            ->view('emails.client') // this is your email template in "view" directory

            ->with([

            'name'  =>  $this->infos['name'],

            'email'  =>  $this->infos['email'],

            ]);

        }

    }
```

Then, you have your email template (resources/views/emails/client.blade.php)

```html
    @if($name)

    <p>Name: {{  $name  }}</p>

    @endif



    @if($email)

    <p>Email: {{  $email  }}</p>

    @endif
```

I hope this helped you.