# How to pass data from database to Mailable?

Tags: laravel, database, email, controller

I know how to pass data to `view` but how do you pass data to a `mailable`? I'm also a bit confused  on where to put the database call `DB::select`, in the `controller` or the `mailable`? So far I've tried this:

**`web.php`**:

```
Route::get('/test-email', 'App\Http\Controllers\TestMailController@test');
```

**`TestMailController.php`**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Mail\ContactMail;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class TestMailController extends Controller
{
    public function test()
    {
        return new ContactMail();
    }
}
```

**`TestMail.php`**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use phpDocumentor\Reflection\DocBlock\Tags\Var_;

class TestMail extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $data;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->data = DB::select('select * from db_name');
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.testmail')->with('data', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.4 Mail, passing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42646751/laravel-5-4-mail-passing-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `$this` :

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->markdown('emails.testmail')->with('data', $this->data);
}
```